# Android listview first and last item selected on small screen device

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-listview

I have a problem with my ListView on devices with small screen, when we click on first item of the list and we scroll to the end, we see the last item selected with the color of the first item.

Part of my adapter code :

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView mItemTitleView;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(this.mLayoutId, parent, false);

        viewHolder.mItemTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemtitle);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Typeface futura_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Futura.ttf");
    viewHolder.mRadioNameView.setTypeface(futura_font);

    viewHolder.mItemTitleView.setText("Something");

    return convertView;
}
```

Device for test : Samsung Galaxy S2 on Android 2.3.7.

Screenshots :

- Top of the list and first item is selected : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClDZe.jpg
- After scroll, we see the last item is selected but we haven't clicked on it : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mU0ak.jpg

Comment: what do you do when the item is clicked? post that code too

Comment: Where is your click event? Also initialize your `ViewHolder` object in `if(convertView==null) {` condition.

Comment: what way you are using to show selection for item

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact problem a week ago.
the code you use to highlight your item has to be in your getView function and not outside of it, because getView is called everytime you scroll.

add it like so:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(this.mLayoutId, parent, false);

        viewHolder.mItemTitleView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemtitle);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Typeface futura_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/Futura.ttf");
    viewHolder.mRadioNameView.setTypeface(futura_font);

    viewHolder.mItemTitleView.setText("Something");
    if(getItemAtPosition(position).isHighlighted){
        //add hightlighting to item like you did outside of getView
        //in your app, highlighting an item makes its text red
        //so you should put the code that makes the text red here
     }
    return convertView;
}
```

this will work if for every item you saved a boolean higlighted variable.

after you add this, getView will not mistakenly add highlighting to your last item.

Comment: " getItemAtPosition(position).isHighlighted " isnt the exact syntax, but I hope you get the point

Answer (score 1):

I had faced the same, you can create an anim folder in res folder, see the code below
 create a file name say ,
  bg_press.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item android:state_pressed="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/bg_press_default" /> <!-- pressed -->
 <item android:state_focused="true"
 android:drawable="@drawable/bg_item_list" /> <!-- focused -->
 <item  android:drawable="@drawable/bg_item" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Note : you can also use colours in place of image as background in this file.

in your row xml use this as,

```
 android:background="bg_press"
```

Hope this will help you